Is my 6Mon Swedish StudentResidentPermit akin to SchenzenTypeC-Visa allowing me to enter Copenhagen first for 2days & then travel to my Univ inSweden?

I have recently been granted a 6-month Swedish Student Residence Permit application by Migrationsverket to attend a 5-6 month student exchange program at Linnaeus University, Kalmar, Sweden.

I propose to land at Copenhagen from India on the 25th of August, 2024 late evening. I have a valid Indian passport

I wish to spend two nights (25th and 26th) in Copenhagen with a family friend (Danish national) before boarding a train from Copenhagen to Kalmar on the 27th August  morning.
The Query ! 

Will the Danish Immigration authorities at Copenhagen, Denmark allow me to step out of  the Copenhagen airport   on the 25th of August so that I can spend   two nights in Copenhegan (prior to my travel to Kalmar by train on the  27th) on the strength of my Swedish Residence Permit alone ?

Please note that I will not have any kind of Danish visa with me when I land first at Copenhagen from India. I will  only have with me the Student Swedish Resident Permit and my valid Indian passport and Swedish University Admission/other supporting documents.


I hope I will be allowed to stay in Copenhagen for 2 days (Denmark being my first landing aiport from India and not Sweden)  before travelling to Kalmar in Sweden based on these documents. Thanks

This is very likely a duplicate question, we have many people asking about entering a different country from where the visa is from. But while I look for the right one of those, yes you can do what you propose.

Sweden and Denmark are even closer than Spain and the Netherlands, it is very likely the immigration officers at the airport do not even ask about traveling through Denmark to Sweden.

Thanks Willeke. As I wish to stay in Copenhagen for 2 nights after first landing at Copenhagen from India (and not travelling to Kalmar, Sweden by train  immediately after landing), I wanted to be doubly sure that this is lawful and will not pose any problem for me. Many thanks for help.
